# Вывод времени, которое делится на 5

Tags: javascript, время

Задача такая: через js мне надо, чтобы выводились минуты, которые делятся на 5.

Пример:
`12:05, 12:10, 12:15 ... 12:55, 13:00` и так дальше.

Если сейчас `12:02`, то чтобы выводило `12:00`, если `12:04`, то опять же `12:00`, если время равняется `12:05`, то выводило `12:05`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проще всего разделить на часы и минуты, и для минут найти ближайшее число, которое меньше либо равно минутам и нацело делится на 5.

```js
const t = '12:06'.split(':');
console.log(`${t[0]}:${String(t[1] - (t[1] % 5)).padStart(2, '0')}`);
```

Для нескольких часов:

```js
const times = ['12:02', '12:09', '12:11', '12:15'];
for (const t of times) {
  const _t = t.split(':');
  console.log(`${_t[0]}:${String(_t[1] - (_t[1] % 5)).padStart(2, '0')}`);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

можно сделать просто в лоб - дешево и сердито:

```
let time = "12:07";
time = time.substr(0, time.length - 1) + ['0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5'][Number.parseInt(time[time.length - 1])]
```

еще более грубее и сердитее (чтобы с числами не иметь дело вообще):

```
time = time.substr(0, time.length - 1) + {'0': '0', '1': '0', '2': '0', '3': '0', '4': '0', '5': '5', '6': '5', '7': '5', '8': '5', '9': '5'}[time[time.length - 1]]
```

чуть короче, но также сердито:

```
time = time.substr(0, time.length - 1) + ({'0': '0', '1': '0', '2': '0', '3': '0', '4': '0'}[time[time.length - 1]] || '5')
```